# Perl: Can't call method "put" without a package or object reference at ./redirect line 25

Tags: perl

I am trying to have this program take a file from the current server i am working on an put a copy of it under a different folder on another server. I am continuously getting this error `Can't call method "put" without a package or object reference at ./redirect line 25.` I appreciate all help. Here is my program:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use POSIX qw(strftime);
use Net::FTP;


($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst)=localtime();
    my $bdate = sprintf("%02d%02d%02d", $mon+1, $mday-7,$year-100);
    my $edate = sprintf("%02d%02d%02d", $mon+1, $mday-1,$year-100);


    my $host = "xxx.xxx.xx.xxx";
    my $userid = "username";
    my $passwd = 'p@ssword';
    my $s = Net::FTP->new($host, Debug => 0);
    my $login = $s->login($userid, $passwd);

    my $path = "/home/username/homdata_percentage_vs_pn/Missing_Neighbor_030716-031316.csv";
    my $newpath = "Z:/Network/HOM/missing_NL/Missing_Neighbor_030716-031316.csv";


    my $meh = $login->put($path, $newpath);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `login` method doesn't return an object. `put` is a method of the main `Net::FTP` object, call it on the `$s` object instead:

```
$s->put($path, $newpath);
```

Comment: how do i login to the other server then? thank you for the help!

Comment: @m.lochhead: Create a new object, or reuse the existing one.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately it gives me this error and i dont have 54 lines in my code

Comment: `Can't use an undefined value as a symbol reference at /usr/share/perl5/Net/FTP/dataconn.pm line 54.`

Answer (score 0):

here is a copy of the fixed program. it works and does not give me any errors.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use POSIX qw(strftime);
use Net::FTP;

    ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst)=localtime();

    my $bdate = sprintf("%02d%02d%02d", $mon+1, $mday-7,$year-100);
    my $edate = sprintf("%02d%02d%02d", $mon+1, $mday-1,$year-100);
    my $path = "/home/user/homdata_percentage_vs_pn/Missing_Neighbor_030716-031316.csv";
    my $newpath = "/HOM/missing_NL";

    my $host = "xxx.xxx.xx.xxx";
    my $userid = "username";
    my $passwd = 'p@ssword';
    my $s = Net::FTP->new($host, Debug => 0, Passive =>0);
    my $login = $s->login($userid, $passwd);
    my $blah = $s->cwd($newpath)
    my $meh = $s->put($path);
```